# Is there a shorter way to ask if 2 variables are a value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a shorter way in python 3 to write:

```
if a in ('n', 'm') or b in ('n', 'm'):
    print(a)
```

I have been searching but did't find a shorter way.
I am try to type this line shorter:

```
if color1 in ('blue', 'red') or color2 in ('blue', 'red'):
```

Comment: `if 'n' in {a,b}:` - might be shorter characterwise, but not really clearer. why do you need it shorter?

Comment: I am trying to do this:  if color1 in ('blue', 'red') or color2 in ('blue', 'red'):

Comment: you are testing if `color1` is either `"blue"` or `"red"` twice that way ...

Comment: Why does this have to be shorter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write

```
if any(color in ('blue', 'red') for color in (color1, color2)):
```

If will benefit if you have 3 variables or more. If there are only 2 of them, your variant looks fine.

Comment: what if want color1 and color2 in ('blue', 'red')

Comment: If you want both of them to be in the list, you just need to replace `any` with `all`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set`, specifically [`set.isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint):

```
if not {color1, color2}.isdisjoint({'blue', 'red'}):
    print(color1)
```

If two sets are not "disjoint", then they have a common element. This can only be the case if at least one of `color1` or `color2` belong to `{'blue', 'red'}`.

---

If you want to check they *both* belong to `{'blue', 'red'}`, use [`set.issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset) or its syntactic sugar `<=`:

```
if {color1, color2} <= {'blue', 'red'}:
    print(color1)
```

Comment: You can shortcut this via `if {color1, color2} & {'blue', 'red'}`.

Comment: @a_guest, They aren't the same. `set.isdisjoint` short-circuits and has lower time complexity. `set.intersection` actually calculates the entire intersection, not just the existence of non-empty intersection.